# Explicit Ramanujan graph families (Reference Request)

Tags: expanders

I am looking for a reference for explicit families of $d$-regular Ramanujan graphs for fixed $d.$ In particular, I am looking for a family of $d$-regular graphs such that the associated reversible random walk on any such graph has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 1\geq \lambda_2\geq \ldots \geq \lambda_k$ with

$$\max_{2\leq i\leq k} |\lambda_i|\leq \frac{2\sqrt{d-1}}{d}~.$$

I want the absolute spectral gap bounded in this way, and therefore bipartite expanders won't do for me (since then, $\lambda_k = -1$).

Comment: have you checked the survey http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~nati/PAPERS/expander_survey.pdf? see section 5.3.

Comment: You might want to check out constructions by Lubetzky et al and Margulis. The references are mentioned in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.4132v2.pdf. AFAIK explicit families of non bipartite Ramanujan expanders for every degree 'd' are not known.